# connecting lists into a list and printing the list of lists in c (linked list of linked lists)

Tags: c, linked-list

```
$ cat tester.c
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 typedef struct node
 {
    int x;
    struct node *next;
 }node;

 typedef struct
 {
    node *p;
 }list;

 typedef struct stack
 {
    list *q;
    struct stack *next;
 }stack;

 int main()
 {
    //fill the list with numbers
    //link multiple stacks
    int counter = 0;

    list *listone = malloc(sizeof(listone));;

    //make a linked list from 0 - 10
    while(counter < 0)
    {
            node *newest = malloc(sizeof(node));
            newest->x = counter;

            if(listone->p == NULL)
            {
                    listone->p = malloc(sizeof(node));
                    listone->p = newest;
            }//end if
            else
            {
                    newest->next = listone->p;
                    listone->p = newest;
            }//end else
    }//end while

    list *listtwo = malloc(sizeof(listtwo));
    counter = 10;
    //make a second list counting from 10-19
    while(counter < 20)
    {
            node *newer = malloc(sizeof(node));
            newer->x = counter;

            if(listtwo->p == NULL)
            {
                    listtwo->p = malloc(sizeof(node));
                    listtwo->p = newer;
            }//end if
            else
            {
                    newer->next = listtwo->p;
                    listtwo->p = newer;
            }//end else
    }//end while

    stack *s = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->q = malloc(sizeof(list));
    s->q = listone;

    stack *t = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    t->q = malloc(sizeof(list));
    t->q = listtwo;

    //connect the two lists
    s->next = t;                    //not sure if this is correct

    //print linked list of linked lists
    while(s != NULL)
    {
            list *l = s->q;
            while(l != NULL)
            {
                    printf("\n%d", l->p->x);
                    l->p = l->p->next;
            }//end while
            s = s->next;
    }//end while

    return 0;
}
```

the purpose of this little program was to understand the nature of linked lists of linked lists lol. I attempted my best but I am so lost. Basically in the first part a make a list counting from 0-9. Then a second list counting from 10-19. I then try to connect the two lists and print out the final list. If anyone could offer some advice to tackle this I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: 1) `int counter = 0;` ... `while(counter < 0)` : This while-loop does not execute. also Need update `counter`.

Comment: `sizeof(listone)` needs to be `sizeof *listone` or `sizeof list`. And please describe more specifically what the problem with your program is. Finally have you attempted basic debugging such as using a debugger and/or debug print statements to trace the execution of your program? People are expected to do basic debugging before asking.

Comment: You are over-complicating things by separating `node` and `list` in a way that makes little sense. Generally if you are separating the list and data structures, you will have something similar to `typedef struct list { void *data; struct list *next; };` then your `data` can be any structure. To create `list` as you have with a single `node *p` doesn't really help. There are many good linked list example on SO that will help, all you need do is search.

Comment: @kaylum `sizeof list` : Type needs parentheses. E.g `sizeof( list )`

Comment: @kaylum see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/9VHNN9) and reference.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are absolutely right. My bad. I learnt something.

Comment: I am working on a different much larger project. I created this program to 1. understand what it is im doing wrong and 2. make it less complicated if I come onto stack overflow. I apologize if it seemed like I was making this complex for no reason. The structs in my other program had much more variables and wanted to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: Also, I made the edits that were recommended and it seems like only one of the lists is added to the "stack." my output displays: 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 then segmentation fault. It seems as if there is an issue with connecting the two lists together but Im not sure what exactly is wrong with my logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplified modify sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int x;
    struct node *next;
}node;

typedef struct {
    node *p;
}list;

typedef struct lol {
    list *q;
    struct lol *next;
} listOfList;

typedef struct range {
    int start;
    int end;//does not contain this value
    //int step;
} range;

list *make_list(void);
listOfList *make_lol(list *aList);
void rangeTolist(list *aList, range aRange);
void printLoL(listOfList *lol);

int main(void) {
    list *listone = make_list();
    list *listtwo = make_list();

    rangeTolist(listone, (range){ 0, 10});//make a linked list from  0 - 10(10 does not include)
    rangeTolist(listtwo, (range){10, 20});//make a linked list from 10 - 20(20 does not include)

    //connect the two lists
    listOfList *two_lists = make_lol(listone);//listOfList *lol=NULL;listAddLastOfLoL(&lol, listone);
    two_lists->next = make_lol(listtwo);      //listAddLastOfLoL(&lol, listtwo);

    //print linked list of linked lists
    printLoL(two_lists);

    //deallocations

    return 0;
}

static inline void *cmalloc(size_t size, const char *func_name){//malloc with check
    void *p = malloc(size);
    if(p == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc error in %s.\n", func_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return p;
}

list *make_list(void){
    list *new_list = cmalloc(sizeof(*new_list), __func__);
    new_list->p = NULL;
    return new_list;
}
node *make_node(int value){
    node *new_node = cmalloc(sizeof(*new_node), __func__);
    new_node->x    = value;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    return new_node;
}
listOfList *make_lol(list *aList){
    listOfList *new_lol = cmalloc(sizeof(*new_lol), __func__);
    new_lol->q    = aList;
    new_lol->next = NULL;
    return new_lol;
}

void rangeTolist(list *aList, range aRange){
    node anchor = { .x = 0, .next = NULL };
    node *current = &anchor;
    int step = (aRange.start < aRange.end) - (aRange.start > aRange.end);

    for(int i = aRange.start; i != aRange.end; i += step){
        node *new_node = make_node(i);
        current = current->next = new_node;
    }
    aList->p = anchor.next;
}
void printLoL(listOfList *lol){
    while(lol){
        if(lol->q){
            for(node *aList = lol->q->p; aList; aList = aList->next)
                printf("\n%d", aList->x);
        }
        lol = lol->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me alot in understanding what exactly was wrong. the problem was with linking the two lists and now everything works great. I just have to figure out how to free the damn thing now. Cheers